# MVVM: using commands when binding to collection of business model object

Tags: wpf, mvvm, collections, command

There has been debate whether we should bind model properties directly to the view. But most of the xamples online bind model properties to view directly e.g. {`Binding Model.Property`}

I was ceating a simple WPF application where I have a datagrid and each row has a button to show a popup.

Business model looks like:

```
public class DataGridItem
{
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The viewmodel class looks like

```
public class DataGridItemViewModel : NotifyableEntity
{
    public DataGridItemViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<DataGridItem>();
    }
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<DataGridItem> ItemsList { get; set; }

}
```

The `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` property is bound to `ItemsList` property of `viewmodel`. Now in this case if I bind a `Command` to `ViewLog` button in the `datagrid`, then it goes looking for the command in the business model class. 
How can I have the command be defined in the `viewmodel` itself without having to write the proxy/wrapper properties in the `viewmodel`?

Comment: This is precisely why I dislike the binding to the (Business) Model. Before you know it you'll be adding properties to the ViewModel and you will get a lot of strange bindings to bind to both the Model and ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that creating ViewModels for child collections is a pain and an exercise in abstraction induced ceremony, but I don't think you need those view models just to handle a command. You can supply a different DataContext for the `Button` so that it binds to whatever viewmodel (or model) you wish:

```
....
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataGridItemViewModel}">
      <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" DataContext="{Binding DataGridItemViewModel}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
...
```